# Create records for entire month, each month based on past month ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This may sound trivial, but I am trying to create one record for each day of the month (every month) and make it aware of the last month of records. Each user has a daily StatusReport. I need to check the dates for duplicates before creating the next group of monthly reports. I need to do this with a cronotab job, to avoid lagging the system. It could be done every month at 06/1/0000 00:00:00. Just to be clear, certain users will have a boolean flag active, and this should decide whether or not the job is performed for them.

**create_monthly_status_report_job.rb**

```
  class CreateMonthlyStatusReportJob
    
  def perform(*args)
    User.where(status_report_enabled: true).status_reports.create!(created_at: Date.new(...).beginning_of_month...Date.new(...).ending_of_month)
  end
```

Should check last status report to see if status report date exist in the database to avoid duplicates.

**UPDATE**
I tried using find_or_create_by(), but received `PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type: "[2020-01-1, 2020-01-31]"`

**full method below**

```
@user.status_reports.find_or_create_by(created_at: Date.new(2020,1).beginning_of_month..Date.new(2020,1).ending_of_month)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: How do you create records for each day of the month through an active job, but check whether or not the record(s) were created previously to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_or_create_by(created_at: Date.new(...))`

Comment: I forgot all about that!

Comment: How do you find and create a record for the whole month with find_or_create_by? I cannot use a range of values as the date.

Comment: You should use the range as an outer loop and iterate through them

Comment: How do you iterate over the days of the month/year passed by params[:month] and params[:year]?

Comment: found it ((Date.new()...Date..new()).each do {|date| date}